# Can't write BLE gatt characteristic on some devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware

In my application the following code is executed:

```
gatt[0] = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress).connectGatt(context, true, new AbstractCallback(subscriber) {
                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                ... // do something with new characteristic value
                }
            })
```

Where AbstractCallback is:

```
 private abstract class AbstractScaleCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

    ... // fields and constants

    private final byte[] TURN_ON_COMMAND = ...
    private static final String COMMAND_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = ...

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic commandCharacteristic;
    private Subscription subscriber;

    AbstractScaleCallback(Subscription subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            gatt.discoverServices();
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            gatt.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            ... // find other characteristics

            commandCharacteristic = measurementService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(COMMAND_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID));
            commandCharacteristic.setValue(TURN_ON_COMMAND);
            gatt.writeCharacteristic(commandCharacteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(COMMAND_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) && Arrays.equals(characteristic.getValue(), TURN_ON_COMMAND)) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                ... // set up characteristic notifications
            } else {
                ... // throw error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On all my test devices the code yields the same results from the application side - all the callbacks are called in the right order, and **gatt.writeCharacteristic(commandCharacteristic)** method returns 'true'. But it seems that on some of those devices the characteristic value on the peripheral device remains unchanged. Even though, the characteristic change notification seems to work all right.
From what I found, all of the problematic devices seem to share the same series of SoC - Snapdragon 600.
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Check the hci snoop log so you can really see what goes over the air.

Comment: Tried that, but sadly could not get those devices to generate snoop log file :/